# Mongo Count occurrence of key in several documents based upon another key in a colleciton of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

So, i have this document structure

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("60"),
"serialNumber" : "11",
"entityId" : {
    "id" : "1",
    "systemId" : "1"
},
"v" : NumberLong(1)},

{
"_id" : ObjectId("70"),
"serialNumber" : "12",
"entityId" : {
    "id" : "1",
    "systemId" : "1"
},
"v" : NumberLong(1)}
```

like this, there are like 100000 different records in the database in table 'serial_number' in mongo db.

I want to count the serialNumber field for each systemId.
There can be several entries for the field systemId in this table and I need the count for serialNumber for each systemId

For example, if the DB has two records as shown above then the result should be something like this

```
{systemId: 1,
serialNumber_count: 2}
```

if there is another entry for systemId:2 and it has only one record in it then the output should be like this

```
{systemId: 1,serialNumber_count: 2 }, {systemId: 2,serialNumber_count: 1}
```

I wrote the below query but this doesn't give me the desired result

```
db.getCollection('serial_number').aggregate([{$group :{_id :{systemId:'$entityId.systemId'}, count : {$sum : 1}}}])
```

Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Comment: the query looks good and the result is also correct, see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LDttD9NX9uT)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the website that I also tried my query there getting the expected result but when I try running this query in robo3t client it shows me page wise data like 50 records at a time when I increase the page size to like a million records it doesn't show me the data

Comment: but its robo3t pagination, why you want to show all data in a page?, definitely it will take load to show all data together..

Comment: and also after i add the count of system Id from the result the count should equal to the number of records present in the database which isn't after i run my query and that is why i posted the question here

Comment: actually , i need to find out the system Id which has max number of documents in the table so to do that i need the whole data .
And by the way thanks for answering quickly :)

Comment: *which isn't after i run my query* i don't see any problem in your query, might be your missing something else. *i need to find out the system Id which has max number of documents* you can sort by `count` in descending order and limit the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233158/discussion-between-shikhar-chaudhary-and-turivishal).